# how to access some new java classes added to the existing jar from gwt project when we run with Maven

Tags: maven, gwt

I am facing below issue when I am running maven for gwt project.

1. in my project we have  "A" project created by using gwt frame work.
2. "B" project is a java project and we need to access B project classes in "A" project server side.so created a jar for B project and added in A project build path.

Now I need to add some new classes in B project and that new classes should access from "A" project client side.

We can able to add new classes in B project and after running maven for B-project, we are able to see new classes in B-project jar.

But when I run maven for Project A it shows an error like "did you forget to inherit a required module?".

Note: same test projects I have created and can able to access B-project new classes in A-project client side code. But when I am running with Maven it is unable inheriting these new classes.

Kindly advise me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please some one advise me for above query..If the question is not clear kindly let me know so that i can elaborate ...

Comment: which probably means that project A is not getting the right version of the Project B JAR. Are you using the right version number in Project A's pom file?

Comment: But when i run maven commands for Project B i can able to see new classes which i have included in Project B jar.
I have one doubt here.
1)suppose if group id is for project B is :"com.bofa.kiran".
2)And inside this it contains some java classes.and if i create new folder under "com" and added some new classes ,and generated jar for Project B.
3)but in A project pom.xml ,if i give dependancy group id for project B is"com.bofa.kiran" then can we able to access new classes which we created in new folder under "com"?/we can able access only classes which are present in "com.bofa.kiran" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to compile your code into javascript in order to make it accessible from the client side (if we aren't considering requestfactory proxies, web services etc. here). If your code is located outside the GWT module it simply doesn't exist for client side.  Practically this means that you need to extract the client side accessible classes from the B module and put it into A\shared folder for example. Also don't forget to place `<source path="shared" />` into your A gwt.xml descriptor. The drawback of this refactoring of course is that you're allowed to use only ["JRE emulated"](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) classes in your `shared` code.

Another solution would be a creation of a gwt module inside your B project and inheriting it in A project.

Comment: Vadim,
I have added <source path="shared" />,<source path="client" /> in A project .gwt.xml.I have not understood below points from above comment.
1)Practically this means that you need to extract the client side accessible classes from the B module and put it into A\shared folder for example. 
2)Another solution would be a creation of a gwt module inside your B project and inheriting it in A project.

can you please kindly explain me clearly.